# Getting H10 error when deploying Java project with Spring Boot in Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've been trying to deploy a API project made with Maven and Spring Boot. The issue is that my project gets the deploy done, but when checking it says:

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
> served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
> You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs
> --tail

When I check the log, I constantly get

```
2022-06-04T07:53:42.612557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-04T07:53:42.933192+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-04T07:53:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-06-04T07:53:45.626918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nutricare-api.herokuapp.com request_id=e21b99c6-4dbe-4b96-a594-88e6c7ac9a0b fwd="190.237.24.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-04T07:53:45.928115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nutricare-api.herokuapp.com request_id=21bf6abb-e4b3-4e42-b499-e07fa850ae58 fwd="190.237.24.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is the repository: https://github.com/eral23/back-end-nutricare, if someone could check the repo in a deeper way, I'd be eternally grateful because I've been struggling with the solution for many days without any success.

Comment: _"if someone could check the repo in a deeper way, I'd be eternally grateful"_, sorry but that is not how Stack Overflow works. You will need to provide a [mre] in the question itself, accompanied by all the relevant debugging information. If you provide that information, then consider hiring someone to investigate.

Comment: Deploying an application in heroku is a little bit hard first time it will give you this H10 error more often. You can compare your repo with this one if you wish, https://github.com/mahadev-k/RockPaperScissors as this one was successfully deployed to heroku.. The project is based on jar and not on war though.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you don't have to set your port for the application. You need to bind your local port which is by default 8080 for spring boot.
So to fix this you need to bind the port for that need to add application.properties to your project with the below property to the file.

`server.port=${PORT:8080}`